# Number of Branches on a Tree that spans a grid

Tags: combinatorics, trees, directed-graphs

I want to count the arrows of a tree that spans a $n$-dimensional grid in a certain way.

Take a $n$-dimensional grid of equal side length $f$. I'll use $n=2$ and $f=4$ in this example, but the question is for all $n$ or $f$.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\hline
 \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\hline
 \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\hline
 \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Now, if instead of a grid, we 'turn' this into a tree, starting from the top left element, traversing the highest dimension (= the diagonal), then recursively the lower dimension(s), getting this:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc} 
\cdot & \rightarrow & \cdot & \rightarrow & \cdot & \rightarrow & \cdot \\
\downarrow & \searrow & & &  \\
\cdot & & \cdot  & \rightarrow & \cdot & \rightarrow & \cdot \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & \searrow &  \\
\cdot & & \cdot & & \cdot & \rightarrow & \cdot \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & &  \downarrow& \searrow &  \\
\cdot & & \cdot & & \cdot & & \cdot
\end{array}$$

We count the arrows:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{Size} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\text{Dimension 1} & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
\text{Dimension 2} & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{array}$$

The $\text{Size}$ is the side length of the 'matrix' the arrow points to. For example, the $6$ arrows of dimension $1$ are the 'last' ones, pointing to a matrix of side length $1$ each. Similarly, the first diagonal arrow points to a matrix of side length $3$.

The arrow counts seem to follow the following formula:
$$\binom{n}{Dimension}\cdot (f-Size)^{n - Dimension}$$

So, for $Dimension = 1, Size=1$, we get
$$\binom{2}{1}\cdot (4-1)^{2 - 1}=6$$

I'd need an explanation why the arrows counts grow in this way, or just a pointer to a similar question. I'm not sure how to search for this, let alone appropriately tag this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an equivalent formulation of your construction: $(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ points to vertices $(a_1+\varepsilon_1,\dots, a_n+\varepsilon_n)$, where $\varepsilon_i\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i$, and $\varepsilon_i=0$ whenever there is some $j$ such that $a_j>a_i$ (or if $a_i=f$)? In other words, arrows point in the direction(s) of the largest coordinate(s)? If so, it appears that the "dimension" of an arrow refers to $n-\#\{i:\varepsilon_i=0\}$ and "size" refers to $1+f-\max (a_i+\varepsilon_i)$. Does that also agree with what you mean?

Comment: The dimension, yes. Not sure what $max(a_i + e_i)$ is, but I'd venture that you've grasped it.

Comment: Okay, good to know. So, up to perhaps off-by-one errors (re: vertices vs. edges), you're asking how many lattice points in a $n$-cube there are, while accounting for the largest coordinate and how many times it is repeated. This does indeed seem like it would be a binomial (which subset of coordinates are largest?) times a power (what are the other coordinates?). But I'll think it through to see if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some (pseudo?)code that I think describes your recursive process:

```
## Double indexed array M whose elements M[d][s] are the sets of vertices 
##  that have the given dimension d and size s. Each vertex counts the
##  arrow that points to it.
dim_size_array = [[set([]) for i in range(f)] for j in range(n)]

# Takes in a list of current coordinate and active indices
function dim_size_count(C,A)

    if A == []:
        return
    if C[A[0]] == f:
        return

    # Diagonal step: traverse the diagonal in the active indices
    new_C = [C[i]+1 for i in A]
    dim_size_count(new_C,A)

    # Counting step: after returning from an arrow, count its statistics
    dim = len(A)
    size = 1+ f - new_C[A[0]]
    dim_size_array[dim][size].add(new_C)  

    # Dimension-lowering step: deactivate one index to "go down a dimension"
    for x in A:
        new_A = remove(A,x)
        dim_size_count(C,new_A)

# Now do it! Start at (1,1,...,1) with all indices active.
dim_size_count([1 for i in range(n)], range(n))
```

Notice that when a vertex is counted, $1\leq c_i\leq c_a\leq f$ for all active indices $a$ and all indices $i$, with equality if and only if $i$ is also an active index. The counting happens after an arrow has been traversed, using the vertex on its head; so each arrow is counted (and only once by construction: sets do not count multiplicity).

Moreover each vertex is counted with size $1+f-c_a$ and dimension equal to the number of coordinates equal to $c_a$. We may therefore consider this description in reverse: the number of vertices with size $s$ and dimension $d$ is the number of integer points in $[1,f]^n$ with $d$ many largest coordinates having value $(f-s)+1$.

To count these points, first choose the $d$ coordinates that have value $s$; there are $\binom{n}{d}$ ways to do this. Then choose the values of the other coordinates; these can be anything between $1$ and $f-s$ inclusive, and so there are $f-s$ choices for the $n-d$ remaining coordinates.

Applying the product principle yields the desired formula: $\binom{n}{d}(f-s)^{n-d}$.

(Technical note: the point $(1,\dots, 1)$ does not correspond to an arrow. However, it is the unique vertex that would have size $f$ and dimension $n$, and so it doesn't interfere with any of the other counts.)

Comment: I know the code is almost literally as poorly optimized as possible, please don't judge me too bad >.<

Comment: Update: I noticed some inconsistencies in my analysis. At this point I'm pretty confident they are fixed, but do let me know if something still seems off to you.

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. For starters, what are $c_i$ and $c_a$?

Comment: They are C[i] and C[a], coordinates of the relevant vertex; $i$ is an arbitrary index, $a$ is an active one.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your answer from a recursive piece of code. You got the result, which is good, but I'm not sure if I can (should) mark it as answered.

Comment: @ThomasB.:  In my mind, the hard part of this problem is obtaining the  dimension and size of the arrow pointing to a particular vertex, and the hard part of that is recognizing the role of the largest coordinates in the original (recursive) definition. There are a couple potential sticking points: (1) I didn’t write code that you understood (2) you don’t agree that my code formalizes the recursive process you describe (3) I have not convinced you of the fundamental inequality $c_i\leq c_a$ (4) some other aspect of the analysis is not clear. Which of these sound(s) most like your concern?

Comment: (If you have the opportunity to take this to chat, please do)